# Printing field that also contains FS character?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, cut

The record to process in AWK has these possible formats:

`foobar` is fixed length, `serialno` is variable length, and the field I want to capture may  contain zero or more underscores.

```
foobar_823932230_processname.txt
foobar_82393280_process_name.txt
foobar_8239330_foo_process_name.txt
```

**Desired output**

```
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

If I use `FS="[_.]"` then I can `print $3` which works for first record but not 2nd and 3rd.

How can I  capture everything between the serial number and .txt?

I'm editing legacy AWK code that needs changing. Once I correctly capture this field, then the awk process continues to generate additional output.

Comment: A one-liner with GNU sed: `sed -E 's/^([^_]*_){2}//; s/\.[^.]*$//' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `cut + cut` should also work:

```
cut -d_ -f3- file | cut -d. -f1
```

```
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

An `awk` solution would be using this regex:

```
awk '{gsub(/^([^_]+_){2}|\..*$/, "")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 4):

With a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs (e.g. GNU sed and BSD/OSX sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/([^_]+_){2}(.*)\.txt$/\2/' file
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([^_]\{1,\}_\)\{2\}\(.*\)\.txt$/\2/' file
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/([^_]+_){2}(.*)\.txt$/,"\\2",1)} 1' file
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/([^_]+_){2}/,""); sub(/\.txt$/,"")} 1' file
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*[0-9]+_/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:digit:]]+_"} {gsub(/\..+$/,"", $2); print $2}' file
processname
process_name
foo_process_name
```

this works by setting a field separator **FS** to a digit followed by a `_`, and by stripping the resulting variable `$2` of the file extension with **gsub**

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to tweak an existing awk script to accomodate this requirement. It's too bad awk doesn't come with a `join` function, but we can roll our own:

```
function join_fields(from, to, joiner,     result, i, sep) {
  for (i=from; i<=to; i++) {
    result = result sep $i
    sep = joiner
  }
  return result
}
```

Demo:

```sh
awk -F '[_.]' '
  function join_fields(from, to, joiner,     result, i, sep) {
    for (i=from; i<=to; i++) {
      result = result sep $i
      sep = joiner
    }
    return result
  }

  {
      field = join_fields(3, NF-1, "_")
      print $0, "\t", field
  }
' <<END
foobar_823932230_processname.txt
foobar_82393280_process_name.txt
foobar_8239330_foo_process_name.txt
END
```

```
foobar_823932230_processname.txt     processname
foobar_82393280_process_name.txt     process_name
foobar_8239330_foo_process_name.txt      foo_process_name
```

Comment: ++ Really useful `join_fields` function